# Vandermonde Matrix for Polynomial Interpolation - Maple

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, interpolation, maple

I have a problem with the following code in Maple.
I am trying to solve a problem regarding the Vandermonde Matrix for Polynomial Interpolation.
$$\\restart:\\with(LinearAlgebra):\\A := VandermondeMatrix([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 5, 5)\\x := <seq(alpha[i], i = 1 .. 5)>\\b := <1, 2, 3, 4, 5>\\eqnsb := {seq((A . x)[i] = b[i], i = 1 .. 5)}\\$$
This bloc of code is directly copied from my textbook, and the output is not correct.
The ideal output should be:
$$eqnsb:= \begin{Bmatrix}
\\ a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+a_{4}+a_{5}=1,
\\ a_{1}+2a_{2}+4a_{3}+8a_{4}+16a_{5}=2,
\\ a_{1}+3a_{2}+9a_{3}+27a_{4}+81a_{5}=3,
\\ a_{1}+4a_{2}+16a_{3}+64a_{4}+25a_{5}=4,
\\a_{1}+5a_{2}+25a_{3}+125a_{4}+625a_{5}=5,
\end{Bmatrix}$$
then one can solve the coefficients after.
I have no clue how to go about to correct the textbook error.
Could anyone help me out here, please!
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is hard to understand. What is the discrepancy between the result of the execution of this code and the desired result ?

Comment: What is the output of the Maple code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code works fine if entered in 1D (plaintext) Maple Notation.

But in 2D Math input mode the `(A.x)[i]` is being mis-parsed as `(A.x)*[i]`, which of course is not what's indended. What's intended is to index the result `A.x` by `i`.

The following should work in either input mode:

```
restart;
with(LinearAlgebra):
A:=VandermondeMatrix([1,2,3,4,5],5,5):
x:=<seq(alpha[i],i=1..5)>:
b:=<1,2,3,4,5>:
Ab:=A.x:
eqnsb:={seq(Ab[i]=b[i],i=1..5)};
```

That is also more efficient. The original code (even when working ok as 1D input) is unnecessarily inefficient because it recomputes `A.x` for each value of `i` in the `seq` call. The revision computes it just once.

For fun, here are some alternative ways to get the result (in a few forms):

As a list,

```
Equate(A.x,b)
```

As an expression sequence (the operands of that list),

```
Equate(A.x,b)[]
```

or,

```
op(Equate(A.x,b))
```

As a set,

```
{Equate(A.x,b)[]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I highly appreciate your help. I have been stuck on this forever. Finally, I can move on.